# Phpstorm scss file watcher issue

Tags: sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

I have this file structure and wacther configuration:

[image]
The problem is that when I save my scss file the css file is updated in IDE only if I switch focus from IDE window and back again.

P.S.: if I configure scss watcher to compile css files in the same directory where source scss files are located, then css files are uptated right after compilation(as it should).

Comment: In your Deployment entry, under Options -- check "upload external changes automatically" -- should help here.

Comment: It is already checked.

Comment: In such case: **1)** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16410 **2)** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10477 Other than that: if you specify actual file name (instead of just path) in "Output paths to refresh" field -- will it make any diff (i.e. add `/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` at the end, so it points to the same output file as in "arguments" filed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment: alter your path in "Output paths to refresh" to point to the actual output file (as in "Arguments" field) and not just folder: i.e. add `/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` at the end.